# Sum of reciprocals of generalized polygonal numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let us consider the series of the sum of reciprocals of generalized pentagonal numbers $$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3n^{2}-n}\right)=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{22}+\frac{1}{26}+...$$

It seems that the series is convergent, but is it known to which number?

I reasoned the following:

Let it be the sum of reciprocals of triangular numbers $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{T_{n}}=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{21}+...=2$$

Already Euler noted that, if we multiply each term by 3, we obtain $$3+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{10}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{3}{28}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{3}{55}+\frac{1}{22}+\frac{1}{26}+\frac{3}{91}+...=6$$

Reordering conveniently, we have that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{15}+...\right)+...\left(\frac{3}{10}+\frac{3}{28}+\frac{3}{55}+\frac{3}{91}+...\right)+3=6$$

It could be noted that $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{15}+...=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3n^{2}-n}\right)$$

And also that $$\frac{3}{10}+\frac{3}{28}+\frac{3}{55}+\frac{3}{91}+...=3\left(\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{9n^{2}+9n}\right)-1\right)$$

This last formula is the formula of centered nonagonal numbers.

The general formula for the sum of reciprocals of centered k-gonal numbers is $$S_k=\frac{2\pi}{k\sqrt{1-\frac{8}{k}}}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{8}{k}}\right)$$

Therefore, $$3\left(\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{9n^{2}+9n}\right)-1\right)=3\left(\left(\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt{1-\frac{8}{9}}}\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{8}{9}}\right)\right)-1\right)$$

Operating, we get that $$3\left(\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{9n^{2}+9n}\right)-1\right)=2\pi\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\right)-3$$

Therefore, $$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3n^{2}-n}\right)+\left(2\pi\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\right)-3\right)+3=6$$

Subsequently, $$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3n^{2}-n}\right)=6-3-\left(2\pi\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\right)-3\right)$$

$$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3n^{2}-n}\right)=6-2\pi\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$$

$$\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{2}{3n^{2}-n}\right)\approx 2,372$$

Is this reasoning and result correct?

I have checked the literature and found general formulas for sums of k-gonal numbers and centered k-gonal numbers, but not for generalized k-gonal numbers. Are there any general formulas for generalized k-gonal numbers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like: $6-\frac{2 \pi }{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: Thanks @MariuszIwaniuk! I was just editing the question when you answered... I got the same result, so nice!

Comment: Looking for references, I found this interesting recent [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.03434.pdf) using these numbers for arithmetic purposes. (Besides, no other connection with your issue).

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $s$ is the number of sides in a polygon, the formula for the $n$th $s-$gonal number $P(s, n)$ is
$$P(s, n) = (s-2)\frac{n(n-1)}2+n.$$
You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number).

Let $\alpha : = \dfrac{s-2}2$. Then, we have
$$\frac1{P(s, n)} = \frac1{\alpha n(n-1)+n} = \frac1{1-\alpha}\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+\frac{1-\alpha}\alpha}\right)$$
This formula can be derived through [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

It follows
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{P(s,n)} = \frac1{1-\alpha}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+\frac{1-\alpha}\alpha}\right)$$
But notice the RHS summation is (one of) the formula for the [generalized harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Alternative,_asymptotic_formulation) (the much cooler version of the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)) $H\left(\frac{1-\alpha}\alpha\right)$. Therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{P(s,n)} = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}H\left(\frac{1-\alpha}\alpha\right)$$

If you wish to include negative indices, just notice
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty}\frac1{P(s,n)}
&= \frac1{1-\alpha}\sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty}\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+\frac{1-\alpha}\alpha}\right)\\
&= \frac1{\alpha-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+\frac{\alpha-1}\alpha}\right) = \frac1{\alpha-1}H\left(\frac{\alpha-1}\alpha\right)
\end{aligned}$$
and thus
$$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{P(s,n)} = \frac1{\alpha-1}\left[H\left(\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}\right)-H\left(\frac{1-\alpha}\alpha\right)\right].$$

This formula can be simplified :)
Just take the two following properties of the Harmonic Numbers:

- $\displaystyle H(x) = H(x-1)+\frac1x$
- $\displaystyle H(1-x)-H(x) = \pi\cot(\pi x)-\frac1x+\frac1{1-x}$

We have
$$H\left(\frac{1-\alpha}\alpha\right) = H\left(\frac1\alpha-1\right) = H\left(\frac1\alpha\right)-\alpha$$
and thus
$$\begin{aligned}
H\left(\frac{\alpha-1}\alpha\right)-H\left(\frac{1-\alpha}\alpha\right)
&= H\left(1-\frac1\alpha\right)-H\left(\frac1\alpha\right)+\alpha\\
&= \pi\cot\left(\frac\pi\alpha\right)-\alpha+\frac\alpha{\alpha-1}+\alpha\\
&= \pi\cot\left(\frac\pi\alpha\right)+\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}
\end{aligned}$$

Finally
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1{P(s, n)} &= \frac1{\alpha-1}\left[\pi\cot\left(\frac\pi\alpha\right)+\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}\right]\\
&= \frac{2\pi}{s-4}\cot\left(\frac{2\pi}{s-2}\right) +2\frac{s-2}{(s-4)^2}
\end{aligned}$$

This is a very pretty formula, thank you for bringing attention to it!

Here are some of its values:

- Sum of reciprocals of pentagonal numbers $$2\pi\cot\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right) + 6 = 6-\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt 3}$$
- Sum of reciprocals of hexagonal numbers $$\pi\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) +2 = 2$$
- Sum of reciprocals of heptagonal numbers $$\frac{2\pi}{3}\cot\left(\frac{2\pi}{5}\right) +2\frac{5}{9} = \frac{10}9 + \frac23 \sqrt{1 - \frac2{\sqrt5}}\pi$$

Comment: thanks for your great answer! A very pretty formula indeed :)